# VCRUNTIME140.dll error after creating a new env using conda for Anaconda IDE

Tags: python, dll, anaconda

I have a Win7 Pro 64bit sp1 system.  I just did a fresh install of Anaconda 2.4 python version 2.7, which seemed to go fine.  I then created an env with python 3.5 and the whole anaconda suite:

```
conda create -n Py35 python=3.5 anaconda
```

The env was created and I have essentially 2 separate instances of Launcher, Spyder, Jupyter NB etc.--one for each version of python.

So here are the issues:

1. Launcher(Py35) has as its default Environment as python 2.7.10.3 (instead of 3.5?). When I use the drop down and select Py35, and then click on the launch button for the spyder-app, the command window blinks for a second, then nothing else happens.
2. If I choose the Spyder(Py35) desktop icon instead to access the app, I get this error:

> pythonw.exe System Error.
>       The program can't start because VCRUNTIME140.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

The python 2.7 versions of the apps all work fine.  When I do search for the 'missing' .dll, I find 2 instances of it here:

C:\Users\AngelaReyes\Anaconda2\pkgs\hdf5-1.8.15.1-vc14_3\Library\bin

and here:

C:\Users\AngelaReyes\Anaconda2\pkgs\msvc_runtime-1.0.0-vc14_0\Library\bin

So I looked in the env/Py35 folder. The 'pgks' and the 'info' folders that appear in the original Anaconda2 installation, aren't there.  I've attached two images of the folder structures:
[Anconda2 file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKxgn.jpg) and 
[Py35 env file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqiza.jpg)

Being a relative newbie, I'm not sure if I can just copy the missing folders from the original Anaconda installation over to the new env, or how else to get the missing .dll file where it needs to be in order for the Py3.5 version of the apps to open and function properly.

I would really appreciate input on this as it has become quite a bugbear for me.

Thanks,
Angela

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with the latest installer, see https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/443.

You can try to manually install the VC redistributable from Microsoft: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Comment: This worked perfectly. I downloaded the x64 version and I'm now able to open the Py35 Spyder app.

Answer (score 0):

I reach this error after updating Spyder to 4.1.4,
So this is the newer version of  Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads